# A short but stimulating robot-control puzzle

Tags: pattern, visual, strategy

[image: A robot-control puzzle]

The goal of this puzzle is to find a sequence of max 4 commands that will move the triangle through the maze and visit **all** colored squares.

Three types of commands can be used:

- F0 makes the sequence start over.
- The arrows (↑, ↱, ↰) move the triangle (forward) or make it change
  orientation (clockwise, anti-clockwise).
- Xs change the color of the square the triangle is into the color of
  the X.

Each command can (but does not need to) have a color. A colored command is only executed if the triangle is in a square of the same color.

If you want to play around with the mechanics, you can do that [here](https://turing.gausshq.com/p/1y4s5J76Kmfdr). (Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the site.)

CLARIFICATIONS:

- Attempting to move out of the board is not allowed.
- The sequence terminates automatically once all squares have been visited.

Comment: What happens if I attempt to walk off the board? What I can glean from the reference it seems to just die, but I'd like that confirmed (in the answer text).

Comment: Does the sequence of operations need to terminate, or is it OK to put the robot into an infinite loop provided it visits every square in the process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does it:

> [image]

With the 'finishes when have covered all squares' clarification.